# Shift UITableViewCell to one position right

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using a custom UIView as my Table header and that header is overlapping the cell at 0 index.

I'm trying to move all cells of my table view to one position right. i.e

`cell at 0th index should be shifted to 1st index`

`cell at 1st index should be shifted to 2nd index`

until there are cell+1 cells

CODE: `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
    .....

    if (indexPath.row == 0){
        cell.hidden = true
        for(var index = indexPath.row-1; index >= 0; index--){
            indexPath.indexAtPosition(index)+1 = indexPath.indexAtPosition(index) }
```

Error: Cannot assign a value of type '(Int)' to a value type 'Int'

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve here? `indexAtPosition` will return an `Int`, and you are trying to assign an `Int` to another `Int` at left side of you expression (Int+1). So error is evident.

Comment: Is this what you need :`indexPath.indexAtPosition(index)  = indexPath.indexAtPosition(index + 1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the height of header using

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

and then it should not overlap with the first cell and thus you need not to shift the cells

Comment: Yes. The reason for header overlapping is that the height of the section is insufficient (30points by default).

Comment: @Nishant: then change the height and upvote the answer ;)

Comment: The question is about "Table header" and not "section header". So, I am waiting for the user's comment on this, whether this works for him or not.

Comment: Thanks for answering but Unfortunately setting header height does not work. It's not _exactly_ a table header. I will update the question with screenshots.

Comment: @Statik: please provide that I should be able to provide a better solution then